# Reiterative calculate

Tags: r

I have to make a reiterative table that each calculation has to take the previous one. Let me explain, my initial data are:

```
maximum <- 10
minimum <- 2
orderp <-0
Qst <- 6
sell <- c(0, 2 , 2 , 10)
```

Calculated:

```
Qst <- c(6, 4, 2, 0)
Qfin <- c(6,4, 10, 10)
orderp <- c(0,0,8,10)
output<-data.frame(Qst,Qfin,sell)
```

| Name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Qst | 6 | 6-2=4 (Qfin(1)-sell(2) | 4-2=2 (Qfin(2)-sell(3) | 10-10=0 (Qfin(3)-sell(4) |
| orderp | 0 | 0 if(Qst(2) <=min) MAX-Qst(2) | 8 if(Qst(3) <=min) MAX-Qst | 10 if(Qst(4) <=min) MAX-Qst |
| Qfin | 6 | 4 (Qst(2)+orderp(2) | 10 (Qst(3)+orderp(3) | 10 (Qst(4)+orderp(4) |
| sell | 0 | 2 | 2 | 10 |

How can I do something like this? Excel is easy but R is not my field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this requires a small loop to solve, as it is an iterative calculation:

```r
for(i in 2:length(sell)) {
  Qst[i] <- Qfin[i - 1] - sell[i]
  orderp[i] <- ifelse(Qst[i] <= minimum, maximum - Qst[i], 0)
  Qfin[i] <- Qst[i] + orderp[i]
}
```

This results in:

```
rbind(Qst, orderp, Qfin, sell)
#>        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> Qst       6    4    2    0
#> orderp    0    0    8   10
#> Qfin      6    4   10   10
#> sell      0    2    2   10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Using this code in my original dataset I have this: Error in Maximun - QaIn[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator. Can be the loop problem??

Comment: Have you spelled the variable correctly? Including capital letters?

Comment: Yes, I have done

Comment: I have resolved, my sell was obs and I have changed in data.matrix